# SharePoint Online New Experience - Remove View from SP List

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, view

[image: New Experience Ribbon; View Highlighted]

Is there a way to remove the view selector on a SharePoint List (New Experience)?

I have many views that I am publishing to Teams using the website app, and don't want the dropdown to appear (See above).

Answer (score 4):

There is not a way to remove this dropdown, as it functions as the only way to change views in the New List Experience.

In Classic lists, there are ways to add JS to the page so that you would be able to hide things through the JS webpart, however Modern lists do not support this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to restrict the views to certain users, either you can hide using JavaScript/CSS or you need to set  the item level permissions. For that go to list settings >> Advance Settings >> Under Read access